# PHP contact form sends me strange emails sometimes

Tags: php, email, spam, contact-form

My site has a PHP contact form which emails me the form data. It is works well when I test it. Also I have received lots of emails from site visitors via that form but ocassionally I receive very strange emails from the form like the one below:

```
v0lMO8  <a href="http://tqiptnoljxnt.com/">tqiptnoljxnt</a>,
[url=http://fqnyptgpiqbp.com/]fqnyptgpiqbp[/url],
[link=http://atmsirfurmic.com/]atmsirfurmic[/link],
http://uoaxeaumrkvo.com/
```

I have no clue whether there something wrong with the form or this is something deliberately sent to me as spam?

Thanks

Comment: spam or someone trying to find some xss hack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's spam. You need to add some kind of spam protection to your website to avoid such situations - simple question or rewritting code from the image. It should reduce number of this kind of mails.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like spam since the URL is typed in different ways so that one may work for you to click it.

I think you need to secure your form by adding random hidden inputs that are stored in sessions and checked while sending to protect your script from cross-site scripting along with better way of human verification.

Answer (score 0):

It's spam. You options are either:

a) Just live with it if the number of emails is manageable

b) Implement some kind of 'human check'. [Google recaptcha](http://www.google.com/recaptcha) is free + easy to implement one, but bear in mind that it can be annoying for legitimate users, so only do this if you think you can't easily cope with the amount of spam email you receive.